# Python 3 ValueError deleting from list

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, pyside

I'm creating a new game using Python 3 and PySide. The game is a simple UI for the game Password, and basically pulls a random value from a list, displays it, and once done with the value(word), deletes said word from the list, as to not use it twice. The odd problem is that the GUI only allows 4 choosings of a words at a time, then throws a ValueError, saying that the list is empty, which is obviously false, seeing as you only go through 4 words before you get the error.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
from random import *

from game_gui import Ui_main_window
from game_list import cards




class game_window(QtGui.QWidget, Ui_main_window):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(game_window, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setupUi(self)

        global password_label
        password_label = self.password_label

        global get_button
        get_button = self.get_button
        get_button.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked)


    def label_clear(self):
        password_label.setText('Push Button To Get New Word')
        get_button.setText('Push Me To Get A Word')
        get_button.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked)

    def button_rename(self):
        get_button.setText('Push To Clear Word')
        get_button.clicked.connect(self.label_clear)


    def button_clicked(self):
        card_to_play = choice(cards)

        password_label.setText(card_to_play)
        cards.remove(card_to_play)
        self.button_rename()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = game_window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/random.py", line 249, in choice
    i = self._randbelow(len(seq))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/random.py", line 225, in _randbelow
    r = getrandbits(k)          # 0 <= r < 2**k
ValueError: number of bits must be greater than zero

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "game_code.py", line 58, in button_clicked
    card_to_play = choice(cards)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/random.py", line 251, in choice
    raise IndexError('Cannot choose from an empty sequence')
IndexError: Cannot choose from an empty sequence
```

And both those errors show up ~50 times.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: As requested, here's the list.

```
cards = [
    'scripture',
    'miracle',
    'garment',
    'prophecy',
    'tomb',
    'staff',
    'spirit',
    'garden of eden',
    'heaven',
    'sulpher',
    'nephelim',
    'knowledge',
    'armageddon',
    'plague',
    'commandment',
    'sovereignty',
    'resurrection',
    'wine',
    'cherub',
    'sandals',
    'wilderness',
    'gehena',
    'famine',
    'temple',
    'passover',
    'baptism',
    'leprosy',
    'ark',
    'drachma',
    'pharaoh',
    'levites',
    'scroll',
    'chaff',
    'boils',
    'Holy Spirit',
    'dragon',
    'lots',
    'Babylon',
    'tent',
    'parable',
    'scales',
    'Urim & Thummim',
    'scarlet',
    'transfiguration',
    'flame',
    'wild beast',
    'straw',
    'Red Sea',
    'pearl',
    'emerald',
    'swine',
    'demon',
    'Tartarus',
    'wine',
    'turtledove',
    'gnat',
    'camel',
    'garment',
    'shroud',
    'tomb',
    'Most Holy',
    'curtain,'
    'olive branch',
    'dust',
    'Cherub',
    'bull',
    'scorpion',
    'Nephilim',
    'privy',
    'sacrifice',
    'earthquake',
    'abyss',
    'fasting',
    'stake',
    'sling',
    'Samson',
    'Goliath',
    'betrayer',
    'slanderer',
    'murderer',
    'circumcision',
    'astrologer',
    'Hades',
    'chariot',
    'cistern',
    'balsalm',
    'undergarment',
    'bruise',
    'shipwreck',
    'fish',
    'intestines',
    'conscience',
    'curtain',
    'hypocrisy',
    'whitewash',
    'grave',
    'spear',
    'breastplate',
    'helmet',
    'leviathan',    
    ]
```

Comment: Why are you using `global` statements here? Can't you just use `self.get_button` and `self.password_label` everywhere instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cards` is *clearly* empty when this happens.

`len(seq)` is then `0`, causing the `ValueError`, but it's the other exception, `IndexError` that you must worry about.

Your code removes the word immediately in the same function, not at a later time, so every time `button_clicked()` is called you remove a random element from `cards`.

Demo showing the exception with an empty list:

```
>>> from random import choice
>>> choice([])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/random.py", line 249, in choice
    i = self._randbelow(len(seq))
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/random.py", line 225, in _randbelow
    r = getrandbits(k)          # 0 <= r < 2**k
ValueError: number of bits must be greater than zero

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/random.py", line 251, in choice
    raise IndexError('Cannot choose from an empty sequence')
IndexError: Cannot choose from an empty sequence
```

You'll have to find out with debug statements why your list is emptied faster than you think it should be.

Note that you are manipulating a *global* list, so removing choices from that list will not restore them when you finish your game. Your list will continue to shrink as words are removed, until empty.

Perhaps you want to track what words you used instead. Store cards you used in a set:

```
class game_window(QtGui.QWidget, Ui_main_window):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(game_window, self).__init__(parent)

        self.used = set()

        # rest of your `__init__`

    # ...

    def button_clicked(self):
        while True:
            card_to_play = choice(cards)
            if card_to_play not in self.used:
                break
            if not set(cards).difference(self.used):
                raise ValueError('Not enough cards, used {}, can pick from {}'.format(len(self.used), len(set(cards))))

        password_label.setText(card_to_play)
        self.used.add(card_to_play)
        self.button_rename()
```

Now `cards` is left untouched, and each new `game_window` will have a new empty `used` set to fill up. Alternatively, you can reset `used` (set it to a new, fresh, empty set with `self.used = set()`) whenever you want to restart the game.

Comment: That works, but after about the 4th word, the game slows down and now freezes? Doesn’t throw an error, but it becomes unusable and needs a force quit after the 4th word. Hmm There seems to be something special about the number 4...

Comment: @SpencerCaesare: Then your `cards` list is only 4 items small. I've added a debug statement, testing the length of both used and cards, to throw an exception if you used all the cards.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sorry, I'm kind of a newb when it comes to python. When adding that change, it throws an invalid syntax error, saying password_label.setText(card_to_play) is invalid, pointing to the "l" in label...

Comment: @SpencerCaesare: That means on the previous line there is a bracket missing. My mistake, corrected now.

Comment: @MartijnPieters the output to the console: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "game_code.py", line 65, in button_clicked
    raise ValueError('Not enough cards, used {}, can pick from {}'.format(len(self.used), len(set(cards))))
ValueError: Not enough cards, used 96, can pick from 96`

Comment: @SpencerCaesare: so your `button_clicked` method was called 96 times. Not 4 times.

Comment: So seems my loop isn't just doing one thing at a time. Will investigate.